# What justifies $(\frac{1}{2i})^{n-1}=(-\frac{i}{2})^{n-1}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A solution I'm looking at includes the line:

$(\frac{1}{2i})^{n-1}=(-\frac{i}{2})^{n-1}$

I'm just not seeing what algebra justifies this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{i}=\frac{1}{i}\cdot\frac{i}{i}=\frac{i}{i^2}=\frac{i}{-1}=-i$$

Comment: Dang, I was about to post the same thing but you beat me to it

Comment: @PaulSundheim Ah, so it's an imaginary number thing... Thx

Comment: @teadawg1337 Well, there's always next time ;-)

Comment: Well,that's the simplest answer. You can also give an induction-style proof, but it's kind of silly to do. Then again,I always overthink things.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what your looking for: $\frac{1}{i}=-i$

Comment: Indeed it is. Thx